# How can I insert color image into res/drawable?

Tags: android, drawable

Instructions:

```
use Image Asset 
if "Icon Type" select "Launcher Icons" then gone to mipmap.
change to "Action bar and tab icons" then not color.
```

How can I insert color image into res/drawable on android studio 3.1?

[image]

Comment: Whats a color image ? You mean color drawable? or color code ?

Comment: drawable image... I can't import image to res/drawable ...

Comment: it is just a copy/paste action, there is no special part in it...

Comment: Sorry i need use Image asset

Comment: Your instructions seem a bit confused, to me. Anyway, **assets != res/drawable**

Comment: I am sorry to confuse you. It is because I am not familiar with English. 
As you say "Asset is not res/drawable "
but I konw the result was placed on the res/drawable.
but now I can't import image (via image asset ) to drawable.

Comment: Still unclear. **You cannot write to** neither `assets` nor `res/drawable`, at runtime! **You can only read from** there

Comment: Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### 한글

안녕하세요 한글로 쓰고 번역도 따로 돌리겠습니다.
우선 제 문제점은 Android Studio 3.1에서 Generic Image를 추가해서 붙인다면 아이콘을 위해 배당되어 있는 Mipmap으로 가고,

아이콘이 아닌것으로 붙인다면 drawable에는 color가 아닌 grey로 저장된다는 것이 였습니다.
해결은 했는데
android studio 3.1의 Iamge Asset을 사용하지 않고 아래 주소의 AndroidAssetStudio(https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)에서 Generic Icon generator 에서 원그림을 읽은뒤 Alpha 값을 줄이면 원래 색이 나타 납니다.
그뒤 다운받은뒤 이를 paste해주면 drawable에 붙더군요...

#### English

Hello. I am sorry that I am not familiar with English.
Mr.'Reso Coder' solved it. Express one's gratitude...

- connect to https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/
- choice 'Generic icon generator'
- choice 'Image'
- select my.Image
- Color (*Set to transparent to retain original colors*) Alpha vale move to **'0'** then get original color generator image
- *download ... un-pack .... copy folders(drawable-hdml....) and paste...*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6DC8.png)